# Comparable types (objects) can't be compared

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I am getting this mystical error:

> The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s)
>   java.lang.Comparable, java.lang.Comparable

What the heck?

(here's the code)

```
public class BST<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public static class Node<P extends Comparable<P>> {
        P val;
        Node<P> left;
        Node<P> right;

        public Node() {

        }

        public Node(P val) {
            this.val = val;
        }
    }

    Node<T> root;

    private void addValHelper(Node root, Node newNode) {
        if (root.val > newNode.val) { // <-- ERROR IS HERE
            if (root.left == null) {
                root.left = newNode;
            } else {
                addValHelper(root.left, newNode);
            }
        } else {
            if (root.right == null) {
                root.right = newNode;
            } else {
                addValHelper(root.right, newNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing mystical about your error.  In Java, being `Comparable` has nothing to do with being an allowed operand of the `<` or `>` operator.  Mutually `Comparable` objects are compared via their `compareTo()` methods (explicitly).

Comment: I provided all the details in my question. I'm sorry I don't know all of Java's idiosyncrasies -- but that's why I'm here. No need to be snarky.

Comment: @ineedahero small update to my answer - I provided some refactoring of your code to make it more idiomatic. Pinging you since you don't get notifications of question edits :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java doesn't have operator overloading. You can't compare Comparable types with `>`. You need to use `root.val.compareTo(newNode.val)` instead.

As an aside:

- Comparable is an interface, not a class
- You don't need to specify `<P extends Comparable<P>>`
- It might make more sense to move the `addValHelper` code into the Node class itself
- It might make sense for `Node` to implement `Comparable`.

This way, your code feels a lot more idiomatic and you don't expose fields of Node to BST.

```
public class BST<T implements Comparable<T>> {
    private final Node<T> root;

    /** Presumably this is run when a value is added.. */
    private void addValueHelper(Node rootNode, Node newNode) {
        rootNode.attachChild(newNode);
    }

    public static class Node implements Comparable<T> {
        private final T val;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;

        public Node(T val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public int compareTo(Node other) {
            return this.val.compareTo(other.val);
        }

        /**
         * Takes the given node and compares it with the current node.
         * If the current node is greater than the given node, the given node is placed to the left.
         * Otherwise it is placed to the right.
         */
        protected void attachChild(Node newNode) {
            if (this.compareTo(newNode) == 1) {
                if (this.left == null) {
                    this.left = newNode;
                    return;
                }
                this.left.attachChild(newNode);
                return;
            } 

            if (this.right == null) {
                this.right = newNode;
                return;
            }

            this.right.attachChild(newNode);
        }
    }
}
```